# How do I pass a variable (url) and ID into a jQuery .load function?

Tags: jquery, onclick, load

I want to get the url of the product clicked and then load only a certain div of the product page in a sidebar

I the below code works id I remove the + '#product-description'

```
$(function(){
    jQuery(document).on("click",".test-click",function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var el = jQuery(this);
      alert(el.attr("href"));
          $('#content').load(el.attr("href") + '#product-description');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

According to jQuery .load documentation [here](https://api.jquery.com/load/), you need one or more spaces between the URL and the tag, so try `$('#content').load(el.attr("href") + ' #product-description');`